# Sum odd numbers program

Tags: java

I'm writing a program where I'm supposed to make a method that calculates if the passed number is odd. For this method, I also need to check that passed number is > 0, and if not, return false.
I am also supposed to make a second method with two parameters (start and end, which represents a range of numbers) and the method is supposed to use a for loop to sum all odd numbers within that range. The parameter end needs to be greater than or equal to start and both start and end parameters have to be greater than 0.
If those conditions are not satisfied return -1 from the method to indicate invalid input.

This is the assignment:

Write a method called isOdd with an int parameter and call it number. The method needs to return a boolean.
Check that number is > 0, if it is not return false.
If number is odd return true, otherwise  return false.

Write a second method called sumOdd that has 2 int parameters start and end, which represent a range of numbers.
The method should use a for loop to sum all odd numbers  in that range including the end and return the sum.
It should call the method isOdd to check if each number is odd.
The parameter end needs to be greater than or equal to start and both start and end parameters have to be greater than 0.
If those conditions are not satisfied return -1 from the method to indicate invalid input.

I've tried for over an hour now but I'm not doing it correctly because my output is wrong. I've written down the expected results and my results below my code.

This is my code:

```
public static boolean isOdd(int number){
    boolean status = false;
    if(number < 0){
        status = false;
    } else if(number % 2 != 0){
        status = true;
    }
    return status;
}
public static int sumOdd(int start, int end){
    int sum = 0;
    if((end < start) || (start < 0) || (end < 0)){
        return -1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= end; i++){
        if((isOdd(i))){
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The expected result is:

```
System.out.println(sumOdd(1, 100));// → should return 2500

System.out.println(sumOdd(-1, 100)); // →  should return -1

System.out.println(sumOdd(100, 100));// → should return 0

System.out.println(sumOdd(13, 13));// → should return 13 (This set contains one number, 13, and it is odd)

System.out.println(sumOdd(100, -100));// → should return -1

System.out.println(sumOdd(100, 1000));// → should return 247500
```

My result:

```
2500

-1

2500

49

-1

250000
```

Comment: In your for loop where you do you summing, `i` should start at `start`, not at `0`.

Comment: On a side note, I suggest you not to use `false` flag for both even numbers and negative numbers. It will make your code maintenance harder in the long run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't declare variables at the begging of your method, only create them when they are needed. As pointed out by Jordan the problem is with `for` loop  index, it should start from `start`, not 0:

```
public static boolean isOdd(int number) {
    if (number < 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return number % 2 != 0;
}

public static int sumOdd(int start, int end) {
    if ((end < start) || (start < 0) || (end < 0)) {
        return -1;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
      if (isOdd(i)) {
        sum += i;
      }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First, your `isOdd` method only needs to return `true` if two conditions are met: the `number` must be greater than zero and it must be odd. That can be done with a single `return` and a boolean `and`. Like,

```
public static boolean isOdd(int number) {
    return number > 0 && number % 2 != 0;
}
```

Second, your loop should start at `start` (not zero). But, I would then test if `start` is **even**. If it is, increment it before the loop. Then we know we have an initial value that is **odd** so we no longer need to test for oddness in the loop (we can increment by two instead). Like,

```
public static int sumOdd(int start, int end) {
    if (end < start || start < 0 || end < 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    if (!isOdd(start)) {
        start++;
    }
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i += 2) {
        sum += i;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Which should be quite a bit more efficient.